# How to remove apk in production track in Google play console?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I accidentally uploaded application in production and now I am not able to do beta testing. How to remove my application from production?

Comment: increment version and upload newer apk in beta-testing

Comment: You can’t “delete” an app from your dashboard/account, but you can “unpublish” it and hide it

Comment: You can not remove from play console you need to wait untill published on play store then you can unpublished from play store..

Comment: But I need my application in Beta. How can I do that?

Comment: I am also looking for a solution. It looks like you can't have beta only apk when there is already one version in production track

Comment: Same problem here, I accidentally push my dev app to production and now I can't undo it...